# Selecting a specific class with jQuery when you have more then one with the same name

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating an image gallery that is outputting the latest uploaded image using PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo  "<div class='ram-bild'>
<div class='nailthumb-container square'>
<a href='bigpicture.php?id=" . $row['pic_name']  . "'><img src=upload/thumb/" .$row['pic_name']  . "></img></a>
</div>
</div>";
}
```

$result just gets the id from my table.

Now I want to use jQuery to show a text over the image when you hold your mouse on it.

Like this:

No mouse: 
Mouse over: http://piclair.com/data/0ooqy.jpg
But since all images have the same class how would I pull this of with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an instance of `this`

```
$(".ram-bild").hover(function() {
    $(this)... //targets the above element on mouseenter
}, function() {
    $(this)... //targets above element on mouseleave
});
```